# How to make Grid column value as link to redirect page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-grid

```
.Grid(Model)
       .Name("MyGrid")
       .Columns(columns =>
       {
           columns.Add(c => c.ProjectName).Title("Project Name").Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.VerticalName).Title("Vertical Name").Groupable(true).Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.Environment).Title("Environment").Groupable(true).Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.TestName).Title("Test Suite Name").Width(120).ClientTemplate("<a href='http://www.google.com/'>#:TestName#</a>");
           columns.Add(c => c.PassCount).Title("Passed").Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.FailCount).Title("Failed").Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.TotalCount).Title("Total").Width(120);
           columns.Add(c => c.Date).Title("Datw & time").Width(150);
       }).Pageable(a => a.PageSize(10))
       .Groupable()
       .Sortable()
       .Filterable()
       .Render();
```

In above code I want to make TestName as link and when we click it should redirect to other page

Comment: Which page do you want to redirect to? Any controller action?

Comment: To any html @diiN

Comment: And what doesn't work with your code?

Comment: Iam unable to see TESTNAME column as link and eve its is not redirecting to mentioned address

Answer (score 0):

columns.Bound(c => c.TestName).Title("Test Suite Name").Groupable(false).Width(120).Template(@@item.TestName );

It worked for me but unable access my local resource.